# initializer-string for char array is too long. After setting compile sources as Objective-C++ in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I created a new single view project to test this. Inside my ViewController.m here is the code:

I'm not sure why when I set my compile sources as ObjectiveC++ it gives me this error? **initializer-string for char array is too long**

```
static const char _basex[3] = "12"; <-This is always ok
static const char _basex2[2] = "12"; <-Gives the initializer error when compiler set to Objective-C++

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C-string literal `"12"` takes 3 characters, `1`, `2`, and the null terminator.

If you want to initialize the 2 char array, do this:

static const char _basex2[2] = { '1', '2' };

Comment: So how come the compiler doesn't give me an error when I set the compile sources as "According to file type"?

Comment: @mskw - What is the file suffix?

Comment: My guess is that Objective-C fills the array with the first two characters but Objective-C++ sees the 3 byte C-string literal and tells you it won't fit.

Comment: I changed my ViewController.m to ViewController.mm, and left it as Object-C++.  Still same error.

Comment: @mskw - Change it to .mm with "According to file type".

Comment: @mskw See my updated answer on how to initialize the 2 char array.

Comment: If someone were to dive deep on the C vs. C++ language spec, I bet this is one of those things where C++ placed an additional requirement that C does not.  Note that end result is the same as @maddy's code above. Note also that the `char` type (and, by implication, `const char *`) does not mean "null terminated string".

Comment: I think your best bet is to not give the array a size, let the compiler do it for you. static const char _basex[] = "12". If you give a "" string in C++, you must leave room for the null. If you really want an array with two chars and no null, you must use the {'1','2'} form of the initializer. Oops, clearly the answer already says this :-)